# Send Messages from service bus topic to another as batches using IAsyncCollector in Azure Functions keeps retries even after message received

Tags: c#, service, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an azure function which receives messages from service bus topic and send to another using IAsyncCollector. Even after the message received in another topic it's not removed from the sender topic and keep retrying.Any idea why it is happening. Also would like to get some samples to use IAsyncCollector. Or is there any other way in azure function I can send messages in batches?

Comment: Is _reliable_ messaging enabled?  Most EAI products require you to manually remove such messages even if it was received without error.  That or you have multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often this would happen if messages are not completed when received. By default, Azure Function would auto-complete messages if the code executes successfully. Check that you don't override the auto-completion by setting `AutoComplete` to false and that there is no exception during function execution after messages are forwarded to the destination with `IAsyncCollection`, as either of these two would cause the messages to be received and sent multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I had AutoComplete set to false in my service bus trigger attribute . It worked when I remove that. As I got a single function which receives and send messages to another service bus topic. Is IAsynCollector the best way to send messages in batches?

Comment: With In-Process SDK it probably is. The alternative would be to instantiate and use an instance of `ServiceBusSender` but then it would mean establishing a brand new connection rather than reusing the one that is provided OOTB with the trigger.

Comment: I am getting message procesing error(Action =complete, clientId =*****)                  This happens when an error caught in catch block and make a call to the messagereceiver.deadletter.

Comment: Please raise a different question with more details.